# Mock Constructor with constructor-args Object... object

Tags: constructor, mockito, powermock

I want to mock a legacy object in my unit test. Here is constructor:

```
public Class LegacyClass{
    public LegacyClass(Object... obj) {
        super(obj);
    }
}
```

I try to mock it using powerMock like this:

```
whenNew(LegacyClass.class).withParameterTypes(Object.class).
withArguments(anyString(), anyString()).thenAnswer(new Answer<Object>(){
...//Answer impl code
});
```

Here comes to questions:

1. Which Class I should put in withParameterTypes()?
2. Can I put this in @Before setup()?

Comment: He picked up recently.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Object[].class` to access the parameter type of a varargs argument:

```
PowerMockito.whenNew(LegacyClass.class)
            .withParameterTypes(Object[].class)
            .withArguments(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString())
            .thenAnswer(new Answer<Object>() {
                public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation)
                        throws Throwable {
                    // your code
                }
            });
```

I tested and this worked also in the `@Before` method.